# Include a product attribute to the displayed price for out of stock products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I hope someone can help me, I'm REALLY new at this.
I want to modify how prices for products are displayed on my woocommerce site. Specifically I want to target items that are not in stock and instead of displaying the price, display
Last ticketed at ($Price) in (Year)
I have added the Year to my products as an attribute (there is only one year per product). It is called Year.

I have been messing with this snippet and cant get it to work, mainly because I have no idea what I am doing. (This code is a modification of things I have found elsewhere on the web)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'modify_price_out_of_stock_items', 9999, 2 );

function modify_price_out_of_stock_items( $price, $product ) {
global $product;
$year = $product->get_attribute('pa_Year');

if ( is_admin() ) return $price; // BAIL IF BACKEND
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
$year = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_Year', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) ) ;
$price = 'Last ticketed at ' . $price . ' in ' . $year[0];
}
return $price;
}
```

Can someone help me correct this?

I tried that code expecting the text 'Last ticketed at $1000 in 2017'  to appear next to out of stock items. However the Year field does not display.

Comment: Have you assigned `pa_Year` to the product? also try change to `pa_Year` to `pa_year`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code goes in functions.php of theme or child theme.

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'modify_price_out_of_stock_items', 9999, 2 );

function modify_price_out_of_stock_items( $price, $product ) {
    // Check if the product is in stock
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        // Get the 'Year' attribute value
        $year = $product->get_attribute( 'Year' );

        // If the 'Year' attribute is set for the product
        if ( $year ) {
            // Format the price and year information
            $price = 'Last ticketed at ' . wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() ) . ' in ' . $year;
        } else {
            // If the 'Year' attribute is not set, display a generic message
            $price = 'Last ticketed at ' . wc_price( $product->get_regular_price() ) . ' in Year N/A';
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, and it works. Thank you so much, and thank you for taking the time to add the comments to allow me to learn and understand how you structured this. A++++++++++++!

Comment: Great- You're welcome. Please go ahead and accept my answer if it's working as expected.